# Stacking LVT boards upstairs

Tags: floor

I've just had a load of evocore LVT boards delivered (40 packs of 7 boards), which I dutifully dragged into my house. I can't find a weight for each pack, but they are pretty heavy. I took them upstairs and now I'm wondering whether having them stacked up on the floor upstairs is ok (or how many packs is ok to stack). I thought I'd check what is sensible before starting to redistribute packs around the house :D

1980s build ex-council house. They are currently against an exterior wall.

Thanks!

Rachel

Comment: Sometimes it will say on the packaging how high to stack.  Stacks of 5 to 8 high should be okay.  Tipping over will probably be what you want to prevent more of.

Comment: they aren't that high, I've got them quite spread out so only up to 4 packs. It's just the weight on the floor I was concerned about.

Comment: Spread out that much, not much concern about weight on the floor.  A carpet would not like it, but other floor types would be okay.